# How to provide injectable service inside module annotation depending on ConfigService value in Nest.js?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

Inside a Nest.js module I want to construct a provider depending on a configuration service variable (typically an environment variable).

I can easily do this:

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: PublisherService,
      useClass:
        process.env.PUBLISHER_TYPE.toUpperCase() === 'KAFKA'
          ? KafkaPublisherService
          : NatsPublisherService,
    },
  ],
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

but I want to use `ConfigService` instead of `process.env` like this:

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: PublisherService,
      useClass:
        config.get<string>('PUBLISHER_TYPE').toUpperCase() === 'KAFKA'
          ? KafkaPublisherService
          : NatsPublisherService,
    },
  ],
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

This would not work, because I have no instance of `ConfigService` here.

**Question 1**: how to get an instance of `ConfigService` inside the module annotation?

I also tried to use factory instead:

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: PublisherService,
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => {
        return config.get<string>('PUBLISHER_TYPE').toUpperCase() === 'KAFKA'
          ? new KafkaPublisherService()
          : new NatsPublisherService();
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    },
  ],
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

This would work, bit the problem here is that classes `KafkaPublisherService` and `NatsPublisherService` are injectable and can not be directly constructed. I need to resolve them using injection.

**Question 2** How to resolve injectable classes inside factory function?

Comment: Are you able to create both the `Nats` and `Kafak` PublisherService classes?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel - yes. If I just say `useClass:  KafkaPublisherService` or `useClass:  NatsPublisherService` everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you inject both `NatsPublisherService` and `KafkaPublisherService` along with `ConfigService`?

Something like this:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: PublisherService,
      useFactory: (
        config: ConfigService,
        kafkaService: KafkaPublisherService,
        natsService: NatsPublisherService
      ) => {
        return config.get<string>('PUBLISHER_TYPE').toUpperCase() === 'KAFKA'
          ? kafkaService
          : natsService;
      },
      inject: [ConfigService, NatsPublisherService, KafkaPublisherService],
    },
  ],
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

Note that publisher services must be imported to module first if they are not global unlike probably your configModule.

Comment: Looks reasonable at the first glance, but sadly did not worked.
First I had to import and to poviders  `KafkaPublisherService`and `NatsPublisherService`.
After that resolution kind of woreked but could not find other dependencies listed in the same list of providers. `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the NatsPublisherService. Please make sure that the "natsConnectionOptions" property is available in the current context.` If I replace `useFactory` with `useClass` with one of the publishers everything resolves again.

Comment: It is the problem with import/exporting rather than the solution.